# PLS-00103: ERROR.Encountered the symbol "BEGIN" when expecting one of the following: <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier>

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

I create a type:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE NAGULIVE.DEPOSIT_DATA_TYPE AS OBJECT (
  DEPOSIT_NO VARCHAR2 (16 Byte),
  ACCT_NAME VARCHAR2 (128 Byte),
  DEPOSIT_DT DATE,
  EPOSIT_AMT NUMBER (16,2)
);
```

If I execute the function it will show error. I don't know where I'm wrong.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION NAGULIVE.GET_DEPOSIT_DETAIL (IN_F_DATE DATE,IN_T_DATE DATE)
RETURN(NAGULIVE.DEPOSIT_DATA_TYPE) AS
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY(SELECT D.DEPOSIT_NO, ACCT_NAME, DEPOSIT_DT, DEPOSIT_AMT 
        FROM DEPOSIT_ACINFO D 
        INNER JOIN ACT_MASTER  A ON D.CUST_ID=A.CUST_ID 
        INNER JOIN DEPOSIT_SUB_ACINFO DS ON D.DEPOSIT_NO=DS.DEPOSIT_NO WHERE DS.DEPOSIT_DT>=IN_F_DATE  AND DS.DEPOSIT_DT<=IN_F_DATE); 
        END;
        /
```

The error is

```
2/7     PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "(" when expecting one of the following:
          <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> self
          long double ref char time timestamp interval date binary
          national character nchar
4/1     PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "BEGIN" when expecting one of the following:
          <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier>
```

Comment: There is no `return query` in PL/SQL. Please read the manual

Comment: i WAS USING POSTGRESQL, IN THAT RETURN QUERY IS THERE. OKAY. AND HOW TO GET MULTIPLE OUTPUTS IN FUNCTION.

Comment: @suchith [PLEASE YOU DON'T NEED TO YELL TO BE UNDERSTOOD HERE !!!!](http://netiquette.wikia.com/wiki/Rule_number_2_-_Do_not_use_all_caps)

Comment: I NEED MULTIPLE OUTPUTS AS MENTIONED IN THE TYPE.

Comment: @ Sylvain Leroux, I'M NEW TO FUNCTIONS, PLEASE HELP ME OUT.

Comment: @suchithshivali: please unlock your capslock key if you want anyone to take you seriously.

Comment: STOP YELLING AT US! Please read Oracle's PL/SQL manual

Comment: Brothers please tell me how to get multiple out put in functions by considering the above example.PLZ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As little as you understand about `PL/SQL` I doubt you coded the above all by yourself. The error messages refers to the non existing function `QUERY`.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION NAGULIVE.GET_DEPOSIT_DETAIL (IN_F_DATE DATE,IN_T_DATE DATE)
RETURN(NAGULIVE.DEPOSIT_DATA_TYPE) AS
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY(SELECT D.DEPOSIT_NO, ACCT_NAME, DEPOSIT_DT, DEPOSIT_AMT 
           ^^^^^


        FROM DEPOSIT_ACINFO D 
        INNER JOIN ACT_MASTER  A ON D.CUST_ID=A.CUST_ID 
        INNER JOIN DEPOSIT_SUB_ACINFO DS ON D.DEPOSIT_NO=DS.DEPOSIT_NO WHERE DS.DEPOSIT_DT>=IN_F_DATE  AND DS.DEPOSIT_DT<=IN_F_DATE); 
        END;
        /
```

The opening bracket indicates that you want to pass parameters to the function but there is no variable called `SELECT` etc. etc. This of course looks like a `SELECT` statement. You mention `Postgres` in your comments. I know nothing about postgres but if that is something you can do in postgres I can attest you that there is no such thing in Oracle `PL/SQL`.

I guess all this does not bring you further but I must agree with a_horse_with_no_name you must start at square one and start learning `PL/SQL`.

Answer (score 1):

```
create or replace function nagulive.get_deposit_detail(
    in_f_date date,
    in_t_date date
) return deposit_data_type
as
    v_deposit_data deposit_data_type;
begin
    select deposit_data_type(d.deposit_no, acct_name, deposit_dt, deposit_amt)
    into v_deposit_data
    from deposit_acinfo d
    inner join act_master  a on d.cust_id=a.cust_id
    inner join deposit_sub_acinfo ds on d.deposit_no=ds.deposit_no
    where ds.deposit_dt>=in_f_date
        and ds.deposit_dt<=in_f_date;

    return v_deposit_data;
end;
/
```

Although SQL and PL/SQL work well together they are not completely seamless.  Unlike PostgreSQL, A SQL statement cannot be used as a native PL/SQL expression.  Instead, a variable must be declared, the statement must SELECT INTO that variable, and then the variable is returned.

Also there was a minor syntax problem with the return declaration - there should not be parentheses around the return type.  This is different than the return statement, which does optionally allow parentheses.

Those both look like understandable mistakes to me, I'm not sure why this question is getting so much hate.

Comment: Thank you sir. I'm still learning PL/SQL. But I need to develop one report in Ireport Jasper. So that I asked how to get multiple output, If I give input. This was the problem I faced. Thank very much sir.